# Change Field Label depending on View Mode

Tags: views, entities, display-suite

Which way should I go, if I want to change the label of a field depending on a view mode?

Option 1:
Add a themefunction that checks the view mode and then change the label depending on it (would need some help doing this)

Option 2:
Edit it via jQuery

Option 3: 
Use Display Suite, but I think this would be a bit of a overkill, just to change a label

Comment: I would recommend the first option, it is better than the other 2 options.